# How to get logger with specify channel in Symfony Command?

Tags: symfony

I am try to create a symfony Command, And I wanna to log what happens during command executing. So I try to create a logger channel in monolog.yaml:

```
monolog:
    channels: ['download_site']
    handlers:
        download_site:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/download_site_%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: ["download_site"]
```

and get the channel in

```
class DownloadSiteCommand extends Command
{
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $logger = $this->getContainer()->get('monolog.logger.download_site');
    }
}
```

But when I execute the command, error throw:

> In DownloadSiteCommand.php line 31:
>
> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getContainer" of class "App\Command\Do
>    wnloadSiteCommand".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class DownloadSiteCommand extends Command
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->logger->info('...');
    }
}
```

services.yaml

```
App\Command\DownloadSiteCommand:
    tags:
        - { 'name': 'monolog.logger', 'channel': 'download_site' }
```

Comment: it works, I am new to symfony and confused with the `tags` in `services.yaml`, can you explain about `tags` and how ti works with monolog?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom channel for logger without autowiring:

```
/** @var LoggerInterface $logger */
$logger = $this->getContainer()->get('monolog.logger.my_channel');
$logger->warning('Foo');
```